# save a .csv file every minute in vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, csv, vb.net-2010

I am working with Data Acquisition. The data is coming continuos from sensors. In my vb.net program I created a .csv file with a button click. After that, I started timer (every second) to write data to the csv file in a following way:
(As long as I click on Disconnect Button, Data won't be saved in .csv file ~ problem)

```
Private Sub ConnectBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ConnectBtn.Click
    CreateCSVfile(Application.StartupPath & "\" & "Records.csv")
    Timer.Start() 
End Sub

Private Sub CreateCSVfile(ByVal _strCustomerCSVPath As String)
    objWriter.Write("Sensor 1" & ",")
    objWriter.Write("Sensor 2" & ",")
    objWriter.Write("Sensor 3" & ",")
End Sub


Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    objWriter.Write(DataString1 & ",")
    objWriter.Write(DataString2 & ",")
    objWriter.Write(DataString3 & ",")
End Sub
```

and when I click on Disconnect Button, Timer stop and I am using following command to close the file.

```
Private Sub DisconnectBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DisconnectBtn.Click
    objWriter.Close()
    Timer.stop()
End Sub
```

Now, what I want is to initialize one timer more to save data after every minute or may be more to the .csv file automatically. So, in case of any power shutdown I can save my data which may be running above 3,4 hours ..... any help/idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: am I right in assuming that youre just keeping the data in memory in the initial instance?

Comment: What type is objWriter?

Comment: @ simon at rcl - the type is `objWriter = IO.File.AppendText(_strCustomerCSVPath)`

Comment: @SimonPrice yes I am keeping the calculated data (DataString1 is some calculated data) in .csv file

Comment: Why don't you just use `File.AppendAllText`.  This will open the file, write the text and then close the file (and flush the data to disk).  Why keep an open StreamWriter?

Comment: I think you where on the right track - add a second timer for the minute interval. Most likely you can just close and reopen the stream to capture the data. You may just want to accumulate the sub-minute data in memory then append to a file `IO.File.AppendAllText()` when the minute interval ticks over.